# FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

Can any one explain to me what that warning mean

[image]

and here column PM2.5 become like City column whyy?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You selected column `[1:13]` to be filled, but you fill it with the full dataset.

Or with other words, try something like:

```
default.iloc[:, 1:13] = default.iloc[:, 1:13].fillna(default.iloc[:, 1:13].mean())
```

Comment: woow that work !

Comment: please can you tell what wrong did i do

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's working. just compare the code, you see what you've done wrong :-) (As I wrote, you just selected the columns which should be edited with `i.loc[:, 1:13]` , but not the target values. So Column 1 was filled with Column 0 and so on.